# Shlokas about "time, pradhana, maya are eternal" from the third person's view

Tags: upanishads, shloka, maya, prakruti

Srila Prabhupada wrote that the Supreme Lord, souls, prakriti and time are eternal in the Bhagavad Gita introduction. So, I need the shlokas which tell that "time is eternal", "pradhana or prakriti is eternal" and "maya is eternal".  I need these shlokas to explain the universal phenomenon as a physics discussion. Kindly give shlokas from Upanishads which are more like an impersonal explanation or from the third person's view.

Answer (score 3):

In the Avatarnika tika to the Govinda Bhashya(Brahma Sutra Bhashya) of Srila Baladev Vidyabhushan, a Bhalvaveya Shruti is quoted regarding this context :--

भाल्ववेयश्रुति:– 'अथ ह वाव नित्यानि पुरुषः प्रकृतिरात्मा काल इति। अथ
यान्यनित्यानि प्राणः श्रद्धाभूतानि भौतिकानि इति। यानि ह वा उत्पत्तिमन्ति
तान्यनित्यानि। यानि ह वा अनुत्पत्तिमन्ति तानि नित्यानि। न ह्येतानि कदा
नोत्पद्यन्ते नो विलीयन्ते पुरुषः प्रकृतिरात्मा काल इत्येषा।' श्रुतिः।

:-
"       '',     ,
, , ,  ,      .          ,     , ,   , , , , , ,         ,   ,         ()     .            
         ,     , ,   ."

Also its said in Srimad Bhagavatam 2.10.12

dravyaṁ karma ca kālaś ca
svabhāvo jīva eva ca
yad-anugrahataḥ santi
na santi yad-upekṣayā

"       , ,   ,           ,     ,          ,   ."
[image]

Comment: Dear Krsna prabhu, thank you so much(^o^) The above teaching is great. It help me a lot.